# Easiest way to apply series of calculations to similar data frames in R

Tags: r

**The following is an example of how I want to treat my data sets. It might be a bit different to understand how my data frame is structured, but I hope it makes sense**:

First density must be calculated for columns A, B, and C using raw data from columns ADry, AEthanol, BDry ...... (Since these were earlier defined as vectors too, i used the vectors instead data frame columns as it was shorter - ADry_1_0 instead of Sample_1_0$ADry_1_0)

```
Sample_1_0$ADensi_1_0=(ADry_1_0/(ADry_1_0-AEthanol_1_0))*(peth-pair)+pair 
Sample_1_0$BDensi_1_0=(BDry_1_0/(BDry_1_0-BEthanol_1_0))*(peth-pair)+pair
Sample_1_0$CDensi_1_0=(CDry_1_0/(CDry_1_0-CEthanol_1_0))*(peth-pair)+pair
```

This yields 10 densities for both A, B, and C. What's interesting is the mean density

```
Mean_1_0=apply(Sample_1_0[7:9],2,mean)
```

Next standard deviations are found. We are mainly interested in standard deviations for our raw data columns (ADry and AEthanol), as error propagation calculations are afterwards carried out to find out how the deviations sum up when calculating the densities

```
StdAfv_1_0=apply(Sample_1_0,2,sd)
```

Error propagation (same for B and C)

```
ASd_1_0=(sqrt((sd(Sample_1_0$ADry_1_0)/mean(Sample_1_0$ADry_1_0))^2+(sqrt((sd(Sample_1_0$ADry_1_0)^2+sd(Sample_1_0$AEthanol_1_0)^2))/(mean(Sample_1_0$ADry_1_0)-mean(Sample_1_0$AEthanol_1_0)))^2))*mean(Sample_1_0$ADensi_1_0)
```

In the end we semi manually gathered the end informations (mean density and deviation hereof) in a plot-able dataframe. Some of the codes might be a tad long and maybe we could have achieved equal results using shorter codes, but bear with us, we are rookies.

**So now to the real actual problem**

This was for A_1_0, B_1_0, and C_1_0. We would like to apply the same series of commands to 15 other data frames. The dimensions are the same, and they will be named A_1_1, A_1_2, A_2_0 and so on.

Is it possible to use some kind of loop function or make a loadable script containing x and y placeholders, where we can easily insert A_1_1 for instance??

Thanks in advance, i tried to keep the amount of confusion at a minimum, although it's tough!

[Data list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU2ky.png)

Comment: You're making things difficult for yourself by sequentially naming variables, encoding information in the object name. Instead, you [should be using a list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061). It is easy to iterate over a list and store results in another list.

Comment: Alternatively, if your data won't all fit in memory at the same time, write a function where the file name is the input parameter, and iterate over the file names rather than over R object names.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gregor, just read the whole thing about list of data frames, and i will try it out right away. What is the best way to deal with that really long line of calculation regarding error propagation??

Comment: @Gregor i managed to get the list made etc., but i think i'm too new to R to handle these code-heavy solutions. Thanks a bunch for your help, let me know if i'm really close, if not i'll just go back to the slavery with tons of data frames.... Added picture of my lists to the bottom of original post!!

Comment: Your list of data frames looks correct. Now you should be able to apply that to the function i gave below. You can add the error propagation function into the `list (mean = mean (x), sd = sd (x) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of individual vectors you combine the raw data into data frames (or even better `data.tables`) and then subsequently store all the data frames for all runs into a list as @Gregor suggested, you can use this function below and the `lapply` function.

```
my_func <- function(dataset, peth, pair){
  require(data.table)
  names <- names(dataset)
  setDT(dataset)[, `:=` (ADens = (get(names[1])/(get(names[1])-get(names[4])))*(peth-pair)+pair,
                         BDens = (get(names[2])/(get(names[2])-get(names[5])))*(peth-pair)+pair,
                         CDens = (get(names[3])/(get(names[3])-get(names[6])))*(peth-pair)+pair)
                 ][,  .(ADens_mean = mean(ADens),
                           ADens_sd = sd(ADens),
                           AErr =     (sqrt((sd(get(names[1]))/mean(get(names[1])))^2) + 
                                     (sqrt((sd(get(names[1]))^2 + sd(get(names[4]))^2))/
                                        (mean(get(names[1])) - mean(get(names[4]))))^2)* mean(ADens),
                           BDens_mean = mean(BDens),
                           BDens_sd = sd(BDens),
                           BErr = (sqrt((sd(get(names[2]))/mean(get(names[2])))^2) + 
                                     (sqrt((sd(get(names[2]))^2 + sd(get(names[5]))^2))/
                                        (mean(get(names[2])) - mean(get(names[5]))))^2)* mean(BDens),
                           CDens_mean = mean(CDens),
                           CDens_sd = sd(CDens),
                           CErr = (sqrt((sd(get(names[3]))/mean(get(names[3])))^2) + 
                                     (sqrt((sd(get(names[3]))^2 + sd(get(names[6]))^2))/
                                        (mean(get(names[3])) - mean(get(names[6]))))^2)* mean(CDens))
                   ]
}

rbindlist(lapply(list_datasets, my_func, peth = 2, pair = 1))
```

Now, this assumes that you put your raw vectors into data frames with the columns in the order in which they appeared in your example (and that they are the only columns in the data set). If this is not the case, you may just have to edit the indices in the `names[x]` calls. If you wanted to have a little more flexibility, you could also define a list of list with the column names for each data set in your individual raw data sets, add that as an argument to `my_func` and then replace all the instances of `names[x]` with `get(list_column_names[x])`

This function should output a `data.table` with the results for each set of data sets (1-16) in individual rows with 6 columns (ADens_mean, ADens_sd, ...)

**NOTE** since there was no actual data to work with, I can't say for sure that this function does exactly what you want, but I think it will be close. This will also require you to download the `data.table` package.

Comment: I think you are very  close, i'll try what you wrote and what Gregor suggested out in R. I might return to you in case of failure...

Comment: @Chemistry101 check out the edited function, this will give you all of the calculations for each data frame in your list as a single row in the output `data.table`. It is a little more cumbersome to look at, but it should get the job done and run pretty quickly

Comment: @Chemistry101 to clarify my last comment (which when re read, seemed it could be confusing) each data frame in the input list will correspond with a single row in the output `data.table`, i.e. if you have 16 data frames then your output will be 16 rows

Comment: Thanks a lot, an output of 16 rows for my 16 data frames is exactly what i need. I am busy at the moment, but will try it out later and hopefully succeed!